# Is it possible, in Javascript, to add a style property twice to an element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Given a HTML Element object, is it possible to add the same style property twice to it without having to resort to string manipulation?

Consider the following examples:

```
<div style="width: 90%; width: calc(100% - 5em);"></div>
<h1 style="font-weight: bold; font-weight: 800;"></h1>
<p style="color: #cccccc; color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);"></p>
```

As far as I can tell, setting styles through the [`.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) property (e.g. `element.style.color = "blue"`) or the [`.style.setProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration) method (e.g. `element.style.setProperty("color", "blue")`) overwrites existing style properties instead of appending them.

Having multiple definitions of the same property allows us to take advantage of the cascading nature of CSS, letting us use more modern CSS property values when they're available while gracefully falling back to "good-enough" values where more recent additions are not supported. However, the only way I can see to do something like this is through manual string manipulation.

Comment: if you do this the first style will be disabled and the second one enabled

Comment: @Marcus, You can add but it no use. In above example It will consider width:calc() .

Comment: Use CSS classes instead and read on `!important.

Comment: `element.getStyle().setProperty("color", "blue");` or perhaps `element.style.color = "blue";`? This should only change the specified property and not the entire style declaration.

Comment: @Azamantes - I would not suggest using `!important` =(

Comment: If an invalid property is set it should be ignored, just the same.

Comment: Can you not use a style block and then set the class?

Comment: @John The short answer is no.

Comment: @Kaiido If that's true, then it seems like a good answer for the majority of use cases, but the application I'm writing requires the behaviour I've described.

Comment: And what is so special in the behavior you describe that can't be done? Just set the most supported one first then the less supported one. Browser supporting the newest will have the newest and others the older.

Comment: @Kaiido I'm writing a web-based WYSIWYG editor that generates HTML using DOM objects.

Comment: Note that you can add style sheets via the DOM as well, via the [`CSSStyleSheet`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet) interface exposed via `document.styleSheets`. It may be more difficult to keep track of than the way you're doing it now, but it is an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is *not* possible unless you use some custom javascript function.

I guess this is because of the way **CSS specificity** works.

> Specificity is the means by which browsers decide which CSS property
>   values are the most relevant to an element and, therefore, will be
>   applied. When specificity is equal to any of the multiple
>   declarations, the last declaration found in the CSS is applied to the
>   element. Specificity only applies when the same element is targeted by
>   multiple declarations. Source:
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

So when you add the same `property` twice in the `style` attribute, the second one will be applied due to specificity. Knowing this the 'logical' behaviour for Javascript when you set properties with `.style.setProperty("propertyName", "propertyValue")` or `element.style.propertyName = "propertyValue"`. is to overwrite the same property if it already exists, instead of adding a new one.

Comment: "*So when you add the same property twice in the style attribute, the second one will be applied due to specificity.*" Except if the second value of this property is not supported. In this case, nothing will change, which is just the same as if it were declared in CSS. CSS cascading as no importance here.

Comment: Not sure what you're getting at. The way I understood his question was that he wants to add the a property to an existing style attribute that already has that property (and possibly others) that need to be maintained, which does require some manipulation (to append them).

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to accomplish the task you mentioned in your question. (Still wondering where is the special case though).

The cleanest being probably by using classes, directly in your CSS file.
An other one being by appending a `<style>` element with your dynamically created rules in the document.
You could even append new rules to the current [`document.styleSheets`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/styleSheets).

But I'll only focus on the premise of your question.

- Firstly, to get the exact same markup as in your code blocks, you can simply use `element.setAttribute('style', 'prop1: val1; prop1:val2; prop1:val3')`.
  The same rules as if it was already there will apply.
- Secondly, setting an invalid value to an element's `style` property through js will be ignored, just like it is in CSS.

```js
document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url("http://fakeserver.com/myGradientFallback.png")';
document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'linear-gradient(to right, #499bea 0%,#ff51fc 53%,#207ce5 100%)';
document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'awesome-property-that-your-browser-doesnt-support-yet(100%)';
```

So you can be safe using just the same *cascading* as CSS does from your js scripts.